# How can I disable landscape orientation universally?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, device-orientation, xcode9

I'm trying to disable landscape mode for my app and I turned off the settings here

[image]

This turns off landscape for the iPhone but not for the iPad, so I went into the info.plist and tried removing the last two but when I submitted the build to iTunes Connect it said they need to be there... So I don't know if there's a way to disable horizontal mode for the iPad? I want portrait mode to be the only thing on iPhone and iPad.

[image]

This is the error I get.

[image]

Thanks! Hope someone can help!

Comment: Read the error message. Multitasking support on an iPad requires that your app supports all orientations on an iPad. Either disable support for iPad multitasking or choose to support all orientations on an iPad.

Comment: BTW - why do you wish to drop support for landscape on the iPad?

Comment: autolayout loll

Comment: That's a terrible reason to make an app less useful to your users.

Comment: well landscape would actually be useless in this app anyways

Answer (score 2):

Try check `Requires full screen`, i think it will opt your app out of multitasking and wont prompt error anymore when compile

Comment: nope, didn't work. if universal it needs the iPad one

Comment: try check Requires full screen and compile again

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using programming using this :

First you need to enable orientations in General setting tab.

And Remove all key from plist.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
          return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: IInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait) // this enable all portrait orientation for all device
}
```

Comment: i have mentioned comment also.

Comment: this only enables portrait for the iPhone.. not the iPad.

Comment: did you try this ?

Comment: I dont think you understood the question fully

Comment: yes i understood  your question you want only portrait in iphone ,

Comment: no. I want portrait on ALL devices. iPhone AND iPad.

Comment: sorry man, you still didn't understand lol. ONLY portrait for ALL devices. thanks for trying tho! :)